# Set user_id for an object via callback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, associations

**BACKGROUND:** I have a model Post that "belongs_to" users (I'd like to use *post.user* to fetch the post creator) and "has_many, :users through: :user_posts" (I'd like to use *post.users* to fetch users that are not the creator but are able to have and belong to the post)

**OBJECTIVE:** Currently, calling `current_user.posts.create` adds the current_user to post.users, while post.user remains nil.

I know I can simply do this `current_user.posts.create(user_id: current_user.id)`, but is there some way to automatically set the user_id without having to explicitly set it each time? (perhaps in the model via a callback?)

Comment: In Rails 4, I can run in the console: `User.first.posts.create(content: "my content")` and get: `=> #<Post id: 1, user_id: 1, content: "my content", created_at: "2014-02-26 20:12:16", updated_at: "2014-02-26 20:12:16">`. I'll post in GitHub later the example code, but can you paste the models and maybe the migrations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found that the order in which you declare associations makes a difference here:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :user_posts, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users, through: :user_posts
end

current_user.posts.create #=> Link with user_id: nil

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_posts, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users, through: :user_posts
  belongs_to :user
end

current_user.posts.create #=> Link with user_id: 1
```

Comment: I think you only need to have `has_many :posts, through: :user_posts`, it's not necessary `has_many :posts`. See example in [Rails Guides](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association). Probably it's having both what gives you the unexpected behaviour.

Comment: Sorry! I posted the wrong model code - I meant to show Post, not User. Updated to reflect.